# Magento 2 how to set custom customer attribute select values

Tags: adminhtml, magento2.3, customer-attribute

I am successfully able to create custom customer dropdown attribute but how to set select default values ?

I am using that code -

```
<?php
namespace XXX\Customerstatus\Setup;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set as AttributeSet;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

/**
 * @var CustomerSetupFactory
 */
protected $customerSetupFactory;

/**
 * @var AttributeSetFactory
 */
private $attributeSetFactory;

/**
 * @param CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
 * @param AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
 */
public function __construct(
    CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
    AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
) {
    $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
    $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
}

public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
    /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
    $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

    $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
    $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

    /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
    $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
    $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

    $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'custom_customer_status_custom', [
                'type'          => 'int',
                'label'         => 'Custom Customer Status',
                'input'         => 'select',
                'source'        => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Table',
                'required'      => false,
                'user_defined'  => true,
                'sort_order'    => 11,
                'position'      => 11,
                'system'        => false,
                'option'        => ['values' => ['Awaiting Reply', 'Yes', 'No']],
                'is_used_in_grid'       => true,
                'is_visible_in_grid'    => true,
            ]);

    $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'custom_customer_status_custom')
    ->addData([
        'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
        'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
        'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer'],
    ]);

    $attribute->save();
}
}
```

I want "Awaiting Reply" by default it will be selected.

Comment: did you try like `selected => 'Awaiting Reply',`

Comment: ok trying this also

Comment: @magefms tried not working

Comment: how about  using `default` ?

Comment: yes i also tried with default but not working

Answer (score 0):

In your setup script, I think all you need to do is set a default value, for example:

```php
$customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'custom_customer_status_custom', [
    [...]
    'default' => 'Awaiting Reply',
    [...]
]);
```

You will need to delete and recreate attribute.

If that still doesn't work I'm wondering whether you need this

```
'option'         => ['values' => [['Awaiting Reply' => 'Awaiting Reply'], ['Yes' => 'Yes'], ['No' => 'No']],
```

Not 100% that will work though.  Default should work.

Comment: ok checking and let you know